# How to differentiate between value-type, nullable value-type, enum, nullable-enum, reference-types through reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

How to differentiate between value-type, nullable value-type, enum, nullable-enum, reference-types through reflection?

```
enum MyEnum
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public int IntegerProp { get; set; }
        public int? NullableIntegerProp { get; set; }
        public MyEnum EnumProp { get; set; }
        public MyEnum? NullableEnumProp { get; set; }
        public MyClass ReferenceProp { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Type classType = typeof(MyClass);

            PropertyInfo propInfoOne = classType.GetProperty("IntegerProp");
            PropertyInfo propInfoTwo = classType.GetProperty("NullableIntegerProp");
            PropertyInfo propInfoThree = classType.GetProperty("EnumProp");
            PropertyInfo propInfoFour = classType.GetProperty("NullableEnumProp");
            PropertyInfo propInfoFive = classType.GetProperty("ReferenceProp");

            propInfoOne.???
            ...............
            ...............
        }
    }
```

Where in the propInfo...s these information can be retrieved?

Comment: How do you define "basic type"?

Comment: int, float, double........As you can see in MyClass-props. Value-types.

Comment: And what about custom structs? For example it's non obvious to me why you want to differentiate enums from other value types.

Comment: http://en.csharp-online.net/Common_Type_System%E2%80%94Type_Unification

Comment: There are no value types in the above code, a value type is a struct..this is different to a primitive type.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell An `int` is a value type and an `int?` is a value type too. Most primitive types are value types. @Saqib Not sure what you want to tell us with this link. It doesn't contain a definition of what you call "basic type". And it calls `DateTime` primitive, which is wrong. And I've never heard of a `FtnPtr` type, which they list under built-in reference types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you check for enum, nullable, primitve and value types;

```
Console.WriteLine(propInfoOne.PropertyType.IsPrimitive); //true
Console.WriteLine(propInfoOne.PropertyType.IsValueType); //false, value types are structs

Console.WriteLine(propInfoThree.PropertyType.IsEnum); //true

var nullableType = typeof (Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(propInfoThree.PropertyType);
Console.WriteLine(nullableType.IsAssignableFrom(propInfoThree.PropertyType)); //true
```

Note that value types and primitives are different things.  Primitives are simply shorthands that map to types (e.g bool > System.Boolean).  Value types are passed by value; they are struct(ure)s not classes.

Comment: By "Basic" I meant primitive value-types.

Comment: There is nothing available via reflection to indicate whether a type is "primitive". This concept does not really exist for the CLR, as it doesn't treat those types any differently from any other value type. If you have a list of types which you want to consider differently from other value types, then you should maintain that list and look for those types explicitly.

Comment: @Programming Hero: can you tell me what the Type.IsPrimitive property indicates then?

Comment: @ProgrammingHero that isn't quite true; the primitives generally refers to those with **direct** IL support; for example, `int`, `short`, `byte`, `long`, `float` etc all have **direct** IL support; operations such as `+` do not use type operators, but are IL instructions. Contrast, for example, to `decimal` which is **not** a primitive. They very much **are** treated differently. Indeed, on the stack most of them don't even exist: `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort` etc all use `int` at the IL level (during operations; not as their declaration).

Comment: I was unaware of the property, thanks. Its mileage does depend on your definition of "primitive". I'm not aware of anything actually caring about something being "primitive" and more about whether it's a "well-known" type a system can do something with. For example, `String` is not considered primitive by this type system, yet most people would regard strings as being a primitive type.

Comment: @Myles - a better way to check for `Nullable<T>` is using `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`

Comment: Can someone comment as to why this is not the answer now?

Comment: @Marc, can you provide example of how Nullable.GetUnderlyingType is better please? Not disagreeing with you, just not sure I understand, thx

Comment: @Myles for detecting nullable types? `var nullType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType); if(nullType != null) { /* then it is a Nullable<T>, where T = nullType */ }`

Comment: I see that you believe the lie that value types are stored on the stack. Value types are stored on the stack except when they are not stored on the stack, which is almost always.

Comment: @Eric, thanks, question duely edited. Do you have any good refs so I can better understand?

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell: Yes. Search for "The stack is an implementation detail" and "The truth about value types" and you'll find my articles on the subject. The "memory management" tag on my blog has a number of additional articles on aspects of memory management if this subject interests you.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public void Test(Type desiredType, object value)
    {
        if (desiredType.IsGenericType)
        {
            if (desiredType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PropertyType.Name` seems to be giving different output for Non Nullable and Nullable types. May be this could be a bit of help to you.

Actually it gives *Nullable`1   Int32* as the output for Nullable and Non nullable.